# Display li horizontally with wide li elements

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to display a li element side by side so that I can turn it into a content slider.  Because the li elements are so wide they will not display inline.  I know that I can expand the ul width to the width needed however I need that to me a mask with over-flow hidden so that it will be a slider.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deaYn/) of my original code.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="slider">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="video"><iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/70965217?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="692" height="389" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="videotext">
            <div class="videotexttitle">
                    <p>Student Stories</p>
                </div>
            <div class="videotextcopy">
                    <p>At autsdf la veleniet lam fuga.Et modit quiae volesti onetumquib us est laut is aute ndant andia dolupti abor sectate aspernat dempor aut qui aut volorerchit, 
    si officat emquissit eatem. At aut la veleniet lam fuga.Et modit quiae volesti onetumquib us est laut is aute ndant andia dolupti abor sectate aspernat dempor aut qui aut volorerchit, 
    si officat emquissit eatem. </p>
                </div>
        </div> 
        <div class="clear"></div>
        </li>

        <li>
            <div class="video"><iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/70965217?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="692" height="389" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
            </div>

            <div class="videotext">
                <div class="videotexttitle">
                    <p>Student Stories</p>
                </div>
            <div class="videotextcopy">
                    <p>At autsdf la veleniet lam fuga.Et modit quiae volesti onetumquib us est laut is aute ndant andia dolupti abor sectate aspernat dempor aut qui aut volorerchit, 
    si officat emquissit eatem. At aut la veleniet lam fuga.Et modit quiae volesti onetumquib us est laut is aute ndant andia dolupti abor sectate aspernat dempor aut qui aut volorerchit, 
    si officat emquissit eatem. </p>
                </div>
          </div> 
    <div class="clear"></div>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.slider {
    width: 1099px; height: 423px;
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative; /* for overflow: hidden to work in IE7 */
}
.slider > ul {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
.slider > ul > li {
    float: left;
    width: 1099px; height: 423px;
}
iframe.actvideo{
    padding:16px;
}
.video{
    float:left;
    background: url('images/videoround.png');
    width:724px;
    height:423px;
}
.videotext{
    float:right;
    width:301px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/5u2Nj/1/

```
.slider > ul {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.slider > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    white-space:normal;
 }
```

Comment: I think he means like a slideshow (the container isn't actually as wide as the sum of its contents; it has a visible portion the size of one item), possibly with arrows to change the visible item

Comment: Not quite.  They do not appear to be side by side.  I have tried the white-space:no-wrap but to no avail.  I have also tried inline-block

Comment: @user2623887 Is my comment above correct? Or is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/5u2Nj/3/) closer? Do you want a horizontal scrollbar to change the current view?

Comment: @trojansdestroy you fiddle is basically the same as mine, you just made the container wider, how about this http://jsfiddle.net/5u2Nj/5/embedded/result/ ? you just need to adjust the container width

Comment: Correct!  See link: http://www.julietgracedesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Screen-Shot-2013-07-26-at-2.57.20-PM.png

However, I need to be able to hide remaining slides so that why I can't add a large width to the box.

Comment: This one looks more like your image but it's essentially the same technique http://jsfiddle.net/5u2Nj/6/embedded/result, so you will only show one slide at a time?

Comment: Correct.  It will just be a content slider.  This is the end game http://www.julietgracedesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Screen-Shot-2013-07-26-at-3.11.00-PM.png

Both the video and text will slide as one li element

Comment: Check this one http://jsfiddle.net/5u2Nj/11/embedded/result/, I think that solves the positioning problem (you may just need to adjust to your container width) now you need to figure out the sliding part

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, floating elements will break them out of their traditional box. You could do one of a couple of things that come to mind to resolve this issue.

1. Use "display: inline-block" instead of float on your list elements
2. Float your ul. Doing this should keep the li elements contained within their container.

In similar situations I also try to ensure that the li elements do not have any margin or padding.

Comment: I tried to floating the ul but that didn't seem to do the trick.  I have also tried display inline-block.  This seems like a relatively common slider.  I must be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

If the end result of what you're looking for is supposed to be appear as though its in a window, you will have to make the inner container wider.

```
/* Some arbitrary large number to hold the width of your li items */
.slider > ul { width: 10000px; }
```

Demo:
http://codepen.io/mikevoermans/pen/lhvqC

Comment: Great point!  I actually tried this before, the problem is I need it to be a set width to create a mask to hide other slides.  Maybe I'm missing something and there is a better way to do this?